# Como calcular total de columna y mostrarla en tabla

Tags: php, sql

hola gente necesito de su ayuda...
necesito  sacar el total por cada columna y mostrarla abajo de la tabla de datos.
 Asi como esta imagen..

[image: De esta forma]

```html
<?php

if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
    $valueToSearch = $_POST['valueToSearch'];
    $valueToSearch2 = $_POST['valueToSearch2'];
    // search in all table columns
    // using concat mysql function
    $query = "SELECT * FROM facturacion where item_mes  LIKE '$valueToSearch' AND item_anio LIKE '$valueToSearch2' ORDER BY 'item_dia' ASC";
    $search_result = filterTable($query);
}
 else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `facturacion`";
    $search_result = filterTable($query);
}

// function to connect and execute the query
function filterTable($query)
{
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "registrador");
    $filter_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    return $filter_Result;
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PHP HTML TABLE DATA SEARCH</title>
        <style>
            table,tr,th,td
            {
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <form action="sss.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="valueToSearch" placeholder="Ingrese Mes"><br><br>
            <input type="text" name="valueToSearch2" placeholder="Ingrese Año"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="search" value="Filter"><br><br>
            
            <table>
                <tr>
                   
                    <th>Sujetas</th>
                    <th>Agravadas</th>               
                    <th>Total</th>
                    
                </tr>

      <!-- populate table from mysql database -->
                <?php 
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
                <tr>
                    
                    <td><?php echo $row['item_sujetas'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['item_gravadas'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['item_total'];?></td>
                </tr>

                <?php endwhile;?>
            </table>
        </form>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar algo como esto

```
<?php 
$T=0 //ESTA ES LA VARIABLE QUE SUMARA LA COLUMNA
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):
    $T+=$valor; //AQUI SUMAMOS EL VALOR DE CADA RENGLON
    ?>
    <!--
    AQUI MUESTRAS LA VARIABLE DE CADA RENGLON
    -->
    <tr>
        <td><?=$valor?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endwhile;?>
<!--
ESTO ES EL PIE DE LA TABLA
AQUI MUESTRAS LA VARIABLE AL PIE DE LA TABLA
-->
<tr>
    <td><?=$T?></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: podrias explicarme un poco mas ... (lo siento soy muy nuevo en esto)

Comment: Claro agregue algunos comentarios en la respuesta :)

Comment: gracias me salvaste ,funciono perfecto

Comment: Genial @outsider mucho exito!!!

Answer (score 0):

podrias probrar utilizando la siguiente expreción:

```
SELECT SUM(columna1, columna2, columna3,...)
FROM tabla
WHERE condición;
```

te convendria talvez crear una columna al interno que se llame total y rellenarla ejemplo :

```
INSERT INTO tabla (total)
VALUES ((SELECT SUM(columna1, columna2, columna3,...)
        FROM tabla
        WHERE condición;));
```

**EDICION**

```
$queryTotal = "SELECT item_mes, item_anio , SUM(valor) as 'total'  FROM facturacion where item_mes  LIKE '$valueToSearch' AND item_anio LIKE '$valueToSearch2' ORDER BY 'item_dia' ASC";
$total = filterTable($queryTotal);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
     <tr>
         <td><?php echo $row['total'];?></td>
     </tr>
```

algo asi seria
espero que te sea de ayuda

Comment: gracias por comentar,entiendo lo de la consulta pero aun no se como mostrarlo..

Comment: si le agregas el total a la tabla donde tenes los datos de las facturaciones mensuales, la llamas como un campo normal osea
`<?php echo $row['total'];?>` en el fetch, si no queres tocar el database (cosa que te recomiendo para tener guardados los valores y usarlos cuando quieras) podes hacer como te respondio Ruben que es una buena alternativa y funciona ☺

Answer (score 0):

yo haría una consulta donde ya te totalice o agregarle unas pseudo columnas al query existente con los totales:

`$query = "SELECT (SELECT SUM(enero) FROM facturacion) total_enero,
                 (SELECT SUM(febrero) FROM facturacion) total_febrero,
                 (SELECT SUM(marzo) FROM facturacion) total_marzo
          FROM facturacion`